# What does "Whose go is it?" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've seen this sentence but can't translate it correctly.

> Whose go is it?

Comment: In one sense, too bad this question was closed as "entirely answerable with a dictionary." I wonder if any of the closevoters looked up _go_ in a [dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=go)? What a minefield for the learner! On the other hand, this underscores the need to [show your research](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439). Had this question been asked in a more [Yoichi-like manner](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465) (with some dictionary excerpts pasted in), it may have been upvoted instead of closed.

Comment: @J.R. I agree with you that answerable by a dictionary is not the correct reason to close this question,  but I am voting to leave it closed until we see a little more effort put into it.

Answer (score 14):

**"Whose go is it?"** is an informal, colloquial expression meaning, **"Whose turn is it?"** (to make the next move in a game of chess or darts, for instance).

Comment: +1 I like your answer better, and you deserved first crack at it anyway! OP apparently had the same problem as you with the 'blockquote' element, and a subsequent edit trying to make sense of the result bollixed us all.